How can I get rid of the icon bar on mobile Chrome?
Using chrome on an iPhone, I disabled in the settings:

But still the icons show up whenever I click an input field.

How can I get rid of this icon bar? It just consumes space and is useless to me.

Did you quit the Chrome app and restart it? Have you restarted your phone?
